# Use the x axis of an intersection in domain

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to create a plot of two functions using `pgfplots`. The plots are intersecting. One of the plots should change its shape from solid to dashed starting at the intersection.

In the following, I created a simplified example of what I want to achieve. In the example, I manually calculated the intersection to get the domain. **How can I automatically calculate the correct domain?**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    % First plot
    \addplot [name path=f,domain={0:5}] {x};
    
    % Second plot
    \addplot [dashed,name path=g,domain={0:5}] {1 + 0.5*x};
    
    % Get the intersection of plots and mark it
    \draw [name intersections={of=f and g,name=i}] (i-1) circle (2pt);
    
    % Do something useful to calculate the domain
    \addplot [domain={0:2}] {1+0.5*x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: example]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A probably simpler and more general way is to use the `intersection segments`, which become available with the pgfplots `fillbetween` library. While the main applications of the library is to enable fills between segments, it can also be used to draw different segments in different styles.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    % First plot
    \addplot [name path=f,domain={0:5}] {x};
    
    % Second plot
    \addplot [draw=none,name path=g,domain={0:5}] {1 + 0.5*x};
    
    % Get the intersection of plots and mark it
    \draw [name intersections={of=f and g,name=i}] (i-1) circle[radius=2pt];
    
    % Do something useful to calculate the domain
    \draw[  intersection segments={
                of= f and g,
                sequence={R1},
            }]; 
    \draw[dashed,intersection segments={
                of= f and g,
                sequence={R2},
            }]; 
   % \addplot [domain={0:2}] {1+0.5*x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I missed that part. This is exactly, what I was looking for.